Insert into table with if case
Can anyone help me with this query? Is it possible to do something like this? I am very new to SQL.

Table 1 userJobId has 2 columns, userid and jobgroupid
Table 2 tbl14userJob has a14userID and a14jobID as columns

I need to add data to userJobId where userid = a14userID
for jobgroupid = 1 if a14jobID = 'CUPE12MO', jobgroupid = 2 if a14jobID = 'TEACHOCCL', jobgroupid = 3 if a14jobID = 'COOPSTUDENT'
This is the part where I have to add the query
$sql = "INSERT INTO userJobId (userid, jobgroupid) value ";
$sql .= "('$uid', ??? ),";
$db->exec($sql);

How to run an if statement in SQL?

what do you want jobgroupid to be if there is no tbl14userJob with that a14userID?  what do you want jobgroupid to be if there is but a14jobID is not one of the three values you list?

there will be data in tbl14userJob and data will be added to jobgroupid accordingly. jobgroupid will be depends on 14userJob.

Do you mean you want to copy data between tables? https://medium.com/@sebastineamede/understanding-data-redundancy-as-a-beginner-in-sql-d98d67ef76e6. Consider creating a view instead, will always be consistent and up-to-date.

not copy, because those will not be same, userid will be the common data where  jobgroupid = 1 if a14jobID = 'CUPE12MO', jobgroupid = 2 if a14jobID='TEACHOCCL', jobgroupid = 3  if a14jobID = 'COOPSTUDENT'

Or you can use a subquery in place of ??? if you just need one column of one row: INSERT INTO table1 (userid, jobgroupid) VALUES (?, (SELECT ...)). Note that you should not use variable substitution in queries, you should use a prepared statement with parameters.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php for more information about using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

i was thinking to use subquery but was not sure it was a correct way to do it or not. and ??? was not any parameter i put it there as was not sure what to do or get the value

Do learn how to use bind parameters to prevent SQL injection attacks (and bugs).
You do want to use a subquery, something like this (untested):
insert into userJobId (userid, jobgroupid) values (?, (
    select
        case tbl14userJob.a14jobID
            when 'CUPE12MO' then 1
            when 'TEACHOCCL' then 2
            when 'COOPSTUDENT' then 3
        end
    from tbl14userJob
    where tbl14userJob.a14userID=userJobId.userid
))


INSERT .. SELECT is more reasonable, I think. Also I'd recommend to use not CASE but FIELD().

@Akina that would be simpler for this case, yes.  insert into userJobId (userid, jobgroupid) select a14userID, nullif(field(a14jobID,'CUPE12MO','TEACHOCCL','COOPSTUDENT'),0) from tbl14userJob where a14userID=?;

@ysth Thank You. I ended up completely eliminating this new table and just add the column which will indicate the group. My issue as I don't have much experience with sql so I was not thinking proper solution.
